# Search using a Search string in SXA Search service

Tags: sxa, content-search

I have a requirement to implement a custom search box and pull search results based on scope and then present the search results by combining components created using two templates.

I am trying to use the Search method in ISearchService -

```
IEnumerable<Item> results = new List<Item>();
results = searchService.Search("", scopeItem.ID.ToString(), Sitecore.Context.Language.ToString());
```

The Search method is expecting a string query as first argument, which if I pass as my search term is not giving me any results.
But if I query for an empty string, I am getting all items from the Scope in the result set. I am doing string operations to see if any of the fields contains my search term.

Looking for a better way to implement this something like -

```
results = searchService.Search(searchTerm, scopeItem.ID.ToString(), Sitecore.Context.Language.ToString());
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using `SearchService` to build query like this:

```
IQueryable<ContentPage> query = SearchService.GetQuery(new SearchQueryModel
{
    Coordinates = model.Coordinates, //not needed if you are not using geo-search
    ItemID = model.ItemID,
    Languages = model.Languages,
    Query = model.Query,
    ScopesIDs = model.ScopesIDs,
    Site = model.Site
}, out indexName);
```

(*implementation took for SXA code - model which you see is not required, you can pass params in a different way*)

and then just use that query to pull the items:

```
IEnumerable<Item> items = query.Select(r => r.GetItem())
```

This is how it works in the SXA search.

But if you still want to go with `Search(QueryModel model)` method if `SearchService` then keep in mind it's using `GetQuery` method inside anyway. We are using this `Search` method explicitly only in one of out JSON renderings. Here is an example usage:

```
SearchService.Search(new QueryModel
{
    Query = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["q"],
    Offset = Offset,
    PageSize = PageSize,
    Sortings = new List<string>(),
    Languages = new List<string>(),
    ScopesIDs = new List<ID>()
})
```

Comment: I tried this way and still getting no search results -

IEnumerable<Item> results = searchService.Search(Request.QueryString["searchTerm"], scopeItem.ID.ToString(), Sitecore.Context.Language.ToString());

Not sure if this is the right way of instantiating a query object (1st argument to the method call here)

Comment: My examples are form the latest code. I don't know which version of SXA you are using.

Comment: We are using Sitecore 9.0.1 + SXA 1.7.1

Comment: So you should have almost the same code. And it should work, I don't remember any issues related to such behaviour as you described.